# Which function "loops" after deriving it $n$ times?

Tags: derivatives

With **looping** I mean that the identity is returned after deriving a function $n$ times.

---

I know the following examples:

#### n=1:

$$f(x)= e^x = f'(x)  $$

#### n=2:

$$f(x) = e^{-x} = f''(x) $$

#### n=4:

$$ f(x) = \sin(x) = f''''(x)$$
with $$f''''(x) = f'''(\cos(x)) = f''(-\sin(x)) = f'(-\cos(x)) =\sin(x)$$

---

What about $n=3$ in particular? Do you know other loops that work?

Comment: *differentiating*, not deriving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is a [linear homogeneous differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients):
$$
y^{(n)} - y = 0
$$
It has the characteristic equation 
$$
z^n - 1 = 0
$$
with the $n$ complex unit roots $\lambda_k = e^{2\pi k i/n}$, $k \in \{0,\dotsc, n-1\}$, as solutions.

As a linear differential equation, the general solution is a linear combination of solutions. In this case
$$
y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k e^{\lambda_k x} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

The solution to

$$f^{(n)}(x)=f (x)$$

Is given by

$$f (x)=\sum C_ke^{2\pi ki x/n},\ \forall\ k\in\mathbb N,\ 0\le k<n$$

$C_k $ are constants.

Comment: The real and imaginary parts are already examples of such linear combinations. For example $\cos x = \frac{1}{2} e^{ix} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-ix}$ for the case $n=4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{x^{kl+m}}{(kl+m)!}, 0≤m<l$$
is equal to all its various order derivatives, including third.